# What have the US and NATO done in Afghanistan for 20+ years?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, terrorism, nato, afghanistan

I must admit I haven't followed the war in Afghanistan for many years. I know US went in there to find Osama, and they did so in 2010 or something (he was in Pakistan). Then they spent another 10 years there, and now they're out.

But I don't get what exactly the US and NATO have been doing in Afghanistan for 20+ years. That's a long time for the biggest militaries in the world to be doing ... *something* ... what is that something?

Because now that they've left, the Taliban are simply taking back over like nothing happened, and I read somewhere that the Taliban have 100.000 soldiers. So what exactly has the US been doing there? Who have they been fighting against? Who have they been killing? The Taliban seems alive and well, with 100K soldiers, so what have the US/NATO done over there for two decades?

Comment: Closely related question: [Why did the USA stay in Afghanistan for 20 years?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66420/23571)

Comment: There are good answers. So I will just add one more point. There is no "Afgan" nation.  Afganistan is a country with too many identities and the common theme among these identities is religion upto a certain degree. Therefore fundemantals of nation building was lacking which is the nation itself

Comment: Many comments deleted. Please don't use comments to debate the question matter or some related point. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer. If you would like to discuss, please use the chat function. Please try to limit these comments to suggesting improvements to the question.

Comment: Think you answer your own question with "taking back over". For 20 years, the Taliban haven't been in power, and all of there operations were hinder by the need for secrecy and the US's opposition. Sure we had other goals other than pinning the Taliban, but that's not nothing.

Comment: I think this is a legit question that is answerable and needs to be answered, though a little too broad. I think the OP shall narrow the questions to one he cares about the most.

Answer (score 48):

## TLDR:

It would be **grossly unfair** to think that the NATO and US **military** did not try their very best to win this.  Many soldiers paid a very high price and are now justifiably very distressed.  Pretty certain however is that the US and NATO **governments** were careless and overconfident when they engaged in yet another hard-to-win guerilla war.

---

For 20 years, the US + NATO were involved in a counterinsurgency war.  Those are very hard to win for a **foreign** power, Malaysia(UK)`*` was about the only one I can think of *after WW2 involving a Western democracy* `**`.

#### Some counter-insurgencies that were won, by **local** troops:

- Peru vs Shining Path.  75K deaths, about 25K of those civilians killed by the government.
- Spain vs. ETA.  UK vs. IRA.  More *police actions* vs. narrow terrorist bases than full-on wars.
- Indonesia vs. Communists.  Extremely bloody, 500K-1.2M deaths.  (quite possibly not a real insurgency but rather a pretext to suppress political opponents by Suharto - txs @timeskull)

#### Counter-insurgencies that were lost:

- Afghanistan.  Soviets lost.
- Vietnam.  The US lost.
- Algeria.  France lost.
- Vietnam.  France lost.
- (almost forgot) Iraq.  The US was asked to leave and the present Iraqi government is a liability rather than an asset most of the time, being Iran-aligned, minority-oppressing, and incompetent at dealing with ISIS.

### Why are they so hard to win.

Picture yourself as a "good guy" foreign soldier fighting against "bad guys" insurgents.  Your goals are to:

- protect and bring over to your side the civilians

  - you don't speak the local language or know the customs
  - development projects, if successful, can help you
  - winning over local leaders helps too
  - having a competent and credible government that the population likes is the gold standard.  Don't mess this up (but it's your *home politicians'* responsibility and you can assume they'll drop the ball).
  - one [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkspot_Strategy) calls for establishing safe areas for the population by having dispersed troops in outpost providing local security and then spread out your influence.  This however puts you in a static defensive posture and leaves many more-or-less isolated units at risk.
- kill bad guys.  However, since insurgents are essentially badly armed civilians fighting you, every time you kill one, you may anger his cousin/brother/buddy into becoming an insurgent.

  - the bad guys look just like local civilians.  be sure not to kill civilians by mistake!  Hint:  fast aircraft suck at this.

Now, say you are an insurgent, fighting against the foreigners.  Your goals are:

- kill anyone collaborating with the foreigners and neutralize development projects.  Kill any competent local officials.  **This is why talking about nation-building is easy, but hard to pull off**.

  - neutralize foreigner-population communication, which is why killing translators is a popular goal
- [provoke](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacres_d%27ao%C3%BBt_1955_dans_le_Constantinois) foreigners into killing civilians, preferably with [media exposure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E1%BB%B9_Lai_massacre)
- keep the population either [on your side](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/01/world/asia/taliban-justice-gains-favor-as-official-afghan-courts-fail.html) or [too scared](https://www.hrw.org/news/2019/09/17/afghanistan-talibans-criminal-attacks-election-activities) to oppose you.
- kill foreign soldiers.  Not necessarily a huge goal, except it can provoke them to overreact and it's great for morale and propaganda.

The question then becomes whose willpower outlasts the others.  If the regular soldiers are not in a do-or-die situation, i.e. if they are foreigners who can return home when their public tires of the war, there is a good chance the insurgents will win.

If the government/outside power can gradually isolate the population from the insurgents' cause, the manpower replacements for the insurgents will wither.  Extreme [insurgent violence towards civilians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Lucanamarca_massacre) can discredit them.  Successful governments that win over the people can carry that off as well.

Finally, a minority insurgency that is operating against a government in its own country (ETA, IRA) really leaves the government no choice but to continue the fight or solve via negotiations, as the government can't pull out.  The communication problem largely goes away and dead soldiers *may* turn public opinion against you.  Part of the reason why Peru and Indonesia ended up with government wins.  This is also the reason Hamas' terrorism is bound to fail:  their stance that Israel should not exist backs Israel into a corner.

For the rest, well, standard armies are still trying to figure out a foolproof way to win these wars.  Counter-intuitively, you typically need *more* soldiers than there are badly-armed insurgents to win.

For details on how the US and NATO failed, you might as well read Pete W's linked *War Nerd* article, it looks pretty solid:

#### The US government under Rumsfeld`***`:

- **didn't** recognize the importance of nation-building, offering better outcomes to civilians or restraining airpower use early.
- It didn't [commit enough troops in the beginning](https://www.militarytimes.com/news/your-military/2016/07/06/a-timeline-of-u-s-troop-levels-in-afghanistan-since-2001/), as Iraq had priority.
- Most of all, starting with Karzai it's been bad government after bad government.
- However I don't agree all that much with that article's conspirational analysis that *spending $2.4 trillion was the point*, this looks more like an honest error: don't attribute to malice what can be explained by hubris and stupidity.

You also need to consider if you want to "tune" your regular army to be efficient at counter-insurgency:  being nice, helping out with development projects, having weaponry useful to that context rather than good at killing peer-enemy field armies.  That's why a police force approach is best, if you can pull it off.  Also, constant low-level casualties and deployments are a drain on recruitment and retention of career soldiers.

`*` Malaysia is "pretty special".  The Communist insurgents were ethnic Chinese who were distinct from the larger Malay population.  And the UK had pretty much promised to decolonize anyway.  And see Fizz's comment.

`**`.  Why the post-WW2 cutoff date?  Simply put, because Western electorates, over time since decolonization, have become vastly less tolerant of their militaries killing large numbers of people without a critical reason.  It is hard to picture modern French people for example accepting the need to [kill 300K-1M Algerians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algerian_War#Death_toll) to stay in Algeria.  Or Americans acquiescing in [Rolling Thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Rolling_Thunder) and [Linebacker II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Linebacker_II).  See also Fizz and Graham's comments below.

`***` Under Rumsfeld?  As Secretary of Defense, Rumsfeld had a huge, outsized, influence on Afghanistan/Iraq.  In Iraq at least, he managed to sideline the State Department after the initial successful invasion to decide how the US should interact with Iraq.

Comment: The [tactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briggs%27_Plan) used in Malaysia involved [forced] population relocation etc., which quickly became unacceptable in human-rights terms (in the West) not much later thereafter.

Comment: @Fizz  that too.  but they were more effective at the time as well as they involved coercion against the Chinese population which the Malay population *still* does not get along with.

Comment: The American Revolution, can also be viewed as an insurgency: https://www.salon.com/2010/06/03/american_insurgents_american_patriots_t_h_breen/

Comment: I read somewhere that British soldiers were much more successful than US ones in the beginning of the occupation of Iraq, precisely because of the British military's decades of experience with Northern Ireland. I vividly remember an article by an embedded journalist who witnessed both US and British soldiers entering a village. The US soldiers raced onto the village marketplace with their Strykers, yelling orders in English through their megaphones, machine guns locked and loaded. The British soldiers left their vehicles outside the village, entered on foot, weapons down, helmets off, no …

Comment: … sunglasses, no masks, and every solider had learned some basic greetings in the local language, plus, unlike the US soldiers, they had brought a translator with them. I am not surprised that a largely (at least in the beginning) US-led occupation of Afghanistan didn't work out so well.

Comment: You could also add the Boer War.  The British won that by inventing the concentration camp, intending to win the war through mistreatment of the families of combatants.   This wasn't explicitly intended as an extermination policy (unlike the later Nazi camps), but a 50% mortality rate amongst children and 25% mortality rate overall makes the distinction pretty irrelevant.  It's not a way of fighting a war which would be acceptable these days though, even for Russia or Syria.

Comment: I have never seen the Indonesian massacres characterized as a counter-insurgency before!

Comment: @timeskull you're right, looks a bit iffy in the details, possibly a false flag operation and political suppression rather than a full insurgency.  I'll keep it for now - otherwise people like me who weren't familiar w. details will assume i forgot it - but add those qualifiers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag this is a very interesting comment. Does it extend to the British-controlled part of Afghanistan - Helmand province? It had a reputation, IIRC, for being one of the deadliest areas for coalition forces.

Comment: @Bennet: To my knowledge, it only applied during the early stages of the Iraq occupation. Even in Iraq, the differences vanished, as the whole thing went to sh… equally everywhere.

Comment: The first paragraph seems like a typical instance of a modern version of the Dolchstosslegende.

Comment: Eh? The IRA situation was not 'an insurgency won by local troops'. There is a defined peace process negotiated by most of the paramilitary groups and the three governments concerned, initiated by the two main parties. The troops in question had been there for nearly 30 years and they'd still be there and the conflict still going were it not for this peace process.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'd recommend The Jakarta Method if you want to know the details

Comment: @Nobody gotta love cryptic passive-aggressive references to anti-semitic conspiracy theories that have nada todo with the subject at hand.  whatever floats your boat, buddy.

Comment: @AlanB I meant "win" loosely and "troops" as well.  in fact, I did note that both ETA and IRA were more police actions than full on military.  in any case, the reason there was a peace process in the first place was that the IRA had not won militarily.  so given the end result, which was cessation of hostilities and largely preservation of the status quo, yes, i'd call that a "win", even if it wasn't achieved by military means only.  Just to be clear:  the peace process was great and the major contributor to the outcome.

Answer (score 21):

A scathing take, answering the question, or at least going to the origins of the protracted military action, can be found in this 20-year retrospective piece (and rant), entitled ["Was There A Plan In Afghanistan?"](https://exiledonline.com/the-war-nerd-was-there-a-plan-in-afghanistan/) by John Dolan, better known as War Nerd. Note that it was published well before last week's events. No endorsement of the site linked here is implied (the original article is paywalled at the author's own patreon).

Dolan argues that in the critical first years, nation building was nowhere to be found among the priorities of the DoD under Rumsfeld. Moreover, the policy planners intentions and attention was already on Iraq, then considered more strategically promising. Thus the long term aspects of the postwar Afghan endeavor were even more weakly supported.

Subsequently, the reason for not leaving became, for many years, to wait for these increasingly futile nation-building, or at least security-building efforts to be completed.

However the expenditures were not at all aligned with this reasoning, even without the fact that much of the money transferred was lost to corruption. The figures below are from War Nerd quoting the NY Times (original linked within his piece).

- $1.5 trillion - spent on war (regular DoD budget, OCO, base construction)
- $500 billion - on interest (i.e. finance)
- $87 billion - to train Afghan military and police
- $24 billion - on economic development
- $10 billion - on counternarcotics

---

Postscript (my own interpretation):

Among the many factors, the subject of corruption and bribery comes up here and in almost every other answer. Afghanistan's GDP is something like $20B/year (part of which came from the US transfers, that in large part for Afghanistan's own security functions). Given the far larger sums actually spent on the whole thing ($100B+/year as NYT reckons), one possibility may have been to increase, rather than decrease, the bribes- but apply them more intelligently, for instance on civilian infrastructure and programs.

Applying the funds locally to produce more lasting outcomes did not and could not happen, because the Stateside defense industry had priority and claimed as much of the budget for itself as possible. As the budget figures show, leaving just barely enough for the nation building to prevent collapse in the short term, because they didn't want to stop this profitable game.

IMO, this fragile state of affairs had another final effect. IMO, the rapid Taliban takeover was possible because they were able to pull together a better long term package deal (bribery, political concessions, protection racket) for various Afghan political groups. The money part had to be financed from alternate sponsors, and I think we will discover it was. The 20 years of lowball civilian spending and stunted postwar recovery significantly lowered the bar for this outcome.

Comment: Can you please summarize the key points of the article. While it seems like a very relevant article, link-only answers are strongly discouraged

Comment: There's no reason to have an image for what are effectively 5 bullet items.

Comment: @Fizz - Author's own presentation. See actual article, there's a more colorful pie chart too, but it didn't show the negligibly small (in comparison) development budget items, which are the main point here IMO

Comment: I take @Fizz meant there isn't any reason to show text as screenshot in the answer, since the answer contains a link to *The War Nerd: Was There A Plan In Afghanistan?*

Comment: Ok removed the graphic table, replaced with bullet points

Comment: Summary : They spent $32B *more* per year on it than education.

Comment: can we get rid of zee image vs table debate?

Answer (score 13):

The best answer out there, which at the same time is also the answer to the question "What went wrong?", is the ["Afghanistan Papers", published by the Washington Post in 2019](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2019/investigations/afghanistan-papers/afghanistan-war-confidential-documents/).

If you follow the link, you will find an exhaustive source of information about what the USA & Co tried to do and how they failed spectacularly at it.

---

A very brief summary:

Basically, for the last 20 years, the USA & Co have tried to engage in nation-building without having any coherent plan taking into account the various difficulties and cultural challenges that they would be inevitably facing going forth.

Since no one had any idea what they were doing, the main "success" of that endeavor turned out to be fostering a tremendous amount of corruption, permeating Afghanistan from the head of the government over the courts and agencies to the lowest ranks of the newly-trained army.

The people involved already knew that they were failing several years ago, but covered it up and pretended that everything was going according to plan.

---

Sadly, the Afghanistan Papers, when they were released two years ago, gained nowhere near the attention that they deserved, which is why you now see so many people genuinely surprised by how quickly the Taliban steamrolled over Afghanistan.

Comment: While it is true the PP did not receive much attention, I think the surprise goes a bit beyond people simply being ignorant of the realities on the ground.  afaik the speed of the collapse was a surprise to basically everyone -- even the worst case scenarios of the most pessimistic experts were suggesting it would take on the order of 3-6 months, not days.